# Difference between AmazonEc2FullAccess and AmazonVPCFullAccess in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

We have EC2:* permissions in EC2FullAccess policy and  AmazonVPCFullAccess has all the permissions starting with EC2 so does it mean that AmazonVPCFullAccess is a subset of AmazonEC2FullAccess ?

Answer (score 0):

If the policy says ec2:* it is full access to ec2. And if the policy dosen't have any condition or other sids with specific denies it is full access and just not only to the vpc resources.

Comment: isn't it misleading then ? Yes, i understand we should add the condition as per our requirement however default policies should also distinguish the roles as EC2 and VPC are two different components so ideally their policies should also be different. If a user is given EC2 full access he should ideally not be able to create VPC.

Comment: I cant more than agree on that is misleading but where is none vpc:* due to the vpc api is under ec2 api.